# Logging Via WCF Without Slowing Things Down

Tags: c#, wcf, logging

We have a large process in our application that runs once a month. This process typically runs in about 30 minutes and generates 342000 or so log events. Recently we updated our logging to a centralized model using WCF and are now having difficulty with performance. Whereas the previous solution would complete in about 30 minutes, with the new logging, it now takes 3 or 4 hours. The problem it seems is because the application is actually waiting for the WCF request to complete before execution continues. The WCF method is already configured as IsOneWay and I wrapped the call on the client side to that WCF method in a different thread to try to prevent this type of problem but it doesn't seem to have worked. I have thought about using the async WCF calls but thought before I tried something else I would ask here to see if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: Can't give a real answer, but: You are looking for a Message Queue. There is the Microsoft Message Queue as part of Windows, or there is NServiceBus, and possibly others. A Message Queue allows your application to send those files into a local service (so your app doesn't get bogged down) and the Queue then handles sending the messages, error handling/retry and all that stuff. Alternatively, batch the WCF Calls. Don't make calls for each Message but batch 100 and send them in one go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

342000 log events in 30 minutes, if I did my math correctly, comes out to 190 log events per second. I think your problem may have to do with the default throttling settings in WCF. Even if your method is set to one-way, depending on if you're creating a new proxy for each logged event, calling the method will still block while the proxy is created, the channel is opened, and if you're using an HTTP-based binding, it will block until the message has been received by the service (an HTTP-based binding sends back a *null* response for a 1-way method call when the message is received). The default WCF throttling limits concurrent instances to 10 on the service side, which means only 10 requests will be handled at a time, and any further requests will get queued, so pair that with an HTTP binding, and anything after the first 10 requests are going to block at the client until it's one of the 10 requests getting handled. Without knowing how your services are configured (instance mode, etc.) it's hard to say more than that, but if you're using per-call instancing, I'd recommend setting `MaxConcurrentCalls` and `MaxConcurrentInstances` on your `ServiceBehavior` to something much higher (the defaults are 16 and 10, respectively).

Also, to build on what others have mentioned about aggregating multiple events and submitting them all at once, I've found it helpful to setup a static `Logger.LogEvent(eventData)` method. That way it's simple to use throughout your code, and you can control in your `LogEvent` method how you want logging to behave throughout your application, such as configuring how many events should get submitted at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Initially I'm focusing on "send it and forget it". Dump it to the server and let it handle the fallout. If I end up with dropped messages or a log jam at the server I will solve that problem separately. What I'm puzzling over right now is why when I'm sending the message to the server in a separate thread is it affecting my main thread? I see your point about batching the messages for efficiency and I may end up doing that, but purely academically, why isn't the separate thread insulating me from this slow down?

Comment: That's hard to answer without knowing how you implemented the separate thread. If it is related to throttling, though, and the WCF call is significantly more expensive than most of the other operations that take place, it could make sense that it may still be taking a really long time for the program to complete if still only 10 requests are being handled at a time. Is there a way you can tell if everything else has completed and your program is just catching up on the logging requests? Are your timestamps from when an operation completes or when it gets logged?

Answer (score 3):

Making a call to another process or remote service (i.e. calling a WCF service) is about the most expensive thing you can do in an application. Doing it 342,000 times is just sheer insanity!

If you must log to a centralized service, you need to accumulate batches of log entries and then, only when you have say 1000 or so in memory, send them all to the service in one hit. This will give you a reasonable performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) has a buffering system that exists outside the context of the calling thread, so it won't hold up your call while it logs.  Its usage should be clear from the many [appender config examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) - search for the term `bufferSize`.  It's used on many of the slower appenders (eg. remoting, email) to keep the source thread moving without waiting on the slower logging medium, and there is also a generic buffering meta-appender that may be used "in front of" any other appender.

We use it with an *AdoNetAppender* in a system of similar volume and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the traditional [syslog](http://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/syslog/) there are plenty of syslog daemons that run on Windows. Its designed to be a more efficient way of centralised logging than WCF, which is designed for less intensive opertions, especially if you're not using the tcpip WCF configuration.

In other words, have a go with this - the correct tool for the job.