# Logging EntLib LogEntry objects via WCF Service in multi-system solution

Tags: wcf, architecture, logging, enterprise-library

We have a multi-system solution: several web sites and a separate App-Tier implemented / exposed as WCF services.  The web sites all use EntLibs to log stuff - but they need to log to a central DB which is only accessible by the App-Tier.

To get around this we're looking at implementing a WCF service that can have LogEntires sent to it (via a Custom Trace Listener that sends the Log Entries to it).

The decision to use a WCF service is that it's in keeping with the rest of the architecture - and we don't have a lot of time to go doing much else.

I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942714/logging-via-wcf-without-slowing-things-down) and started wondering if we're on the wrong track altogether (from a performance perspective).

So, my question is:

- Is this such a bad idea that I should just stop?
- If it's viable, what are the traps I need to look out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the question you linked to covers it quite well, if you read between the lines:

- Call the WCF logging service with "Is One way" = true, so that your client program does not wait for the logging to complete.
- Set the WCF settings such that the client does not throttle the number of requests